# Gradle Error while running flutter project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, flutter

I am completely new to `flutter`.
Yesterday I installed flutter, added path variables and it works straight from `cmd`.
I also created a project using `cmd` and opened it in `Android Studio`.
Import of `Dart` and `Flutter` `plugins` has done, too.

Then what the problem could be here ?

[image: Gradle_Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that a file that Gradle has downloaded has become corrupted.

Delete the .gradle directories in both your home directory and in your project's root directory and try building again.

Comment: Thanks ! I deleted the old one and replaced it with a new one. It works !

Answer (score 2):

you need to delete cache of android studio and restart build of the project .
go to file in android studio and click in invalidate cache [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABnLl.jpg)